# Is it possible to load JS code from .js file in Twig template as inline?

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, grav

I'd like to load JS code from JS file in Twig template and render it inline. As we can do it in PHP with `file_get_contents('.../js/main.js')`.

I know I can load `main.js.twig`, but I need to load JS code from a file with `.js` extenstion

For example, `main.js` contains:

```
console.log('Works!');
```

And in my Twig template I try:

```
<script>
{% include "#{theme_dir}/js/main.js" %}
</script>
```

to render inline JS code like

```
<script>
console.log('Works!');
</script>
```

but I receive the error

> Template ".../js/main.js" is not defined in ...

In my case Twig is used by CMS Grav

Comment: Are your using your own custom theme, or a public theme?

Comment: My own custom theme

Comment: In the case of a custom template, there is a better Grav idiomatic way of adding assets like js and css. Using AssetManager assets can be bundled and minified before loading into Twig.

Comment: Please accept the answers that solves your issue/question, or which was most helpful in finding a solution to the question/issue.

Comment: @passerby Could you add an example of minifying CSS and JS to your answer?

Comment: It's all in the docs I've linked to, but I'll add it anyway..

Comment: @passerby Of course, I read the docs before posting my comment. And under `assets:` there is `css_minify: true` in the `system.yaml`, but CSS is still not minified. That's why I asked you post an example - I thought maybe I do something wrong. I've even checked on build-in Quark theme - the result the same. What else can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grav has its [Asset Manager](https://learn.getgrav.org/17/themes/asset-manager) with which js/css assets can be added to Twig. Assets can be added as bundle and minified or can be inlined.

In Twig you first define the assets to add in the <head> of the page:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% do assets.addJs('jquery', 101) %}
    {% do assets.addJs('theme://js/jquery.treemenu.js', { group: 'bottom' }) %}
    {% do assets.addJs('theme://js/site.js', { group: 'bottom' }) %}
    {% do assets.addJsModule('plugin://my_plugin/app/main.js', { group: 'bottom' }) %}
{% endblock %}
```

and then load the assets elsewhere in Twig:

```
{% block bottom %}
    {{ assets.js('bottom')|raw }}
{% endblock %}
```

To enable/disable bundling and minification of assets, use the settings in */user/config/system.yaml*. See [AssetManager/Configuration](https://learn.getgrav.org/17/themes/asset-manager#configuration)

```
assets:
  css_pipeline: true
  css_minify: true
  js_pipeline: true
  js_minify: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry - the problem was in the path: JS file should be in `/templates/` directory of Grav theme. Now it works.

Also we can use Grav `read_file()` function to load file content from any directory as variable and change it before rendering if we need:

```
<script>
{% set js = read_file("#{theme_dir}/js/main.js") %}
{{ js|raw }}
</script>
```